# observe KO observable from another viewmodel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal

So I have two view models taking to each other

```js
var viewModel1 = function(){
    this.messageForVM2 = ko.observable("");
    this.message = ko.observable("Hello this is vm1")
};

var viewModel2 = function(vm1){
    this.message = ko.observable(vm1.messageForVM2());
};


var masterVM = (function(){
    this.viewModel1 =  new viewModel1(),
    this.viewModel2 = new viewModel2(this.viewModel1);
})();

ko.applyBindings(masterVM)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h4>View Model 1</h4>
<div data-bind="with: viewModel1">
    <p data-bind="text: messageForVM2"></p>
    <input data-bind="value: messageForVM2, valueUpdate: 'input'" />
</div>

<h4>View Model 2</h4>
<div data-bind="with: viewModel2">
    <!-- ko if: message() === "hello" -->
    <p data-bind="text:message"></p>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

(also over here http://jsfiddle.net/ceryb9pc/)

I want viewmodel2 data-bind to show only if "hello" is the value in the observable in viewmodel1. This works but I want it to work when the value is updated in the viewmodel1 input.

In my example is only works when:

```
this.messageForVM2 = ko.observable("hello");
```

but need to remove like:

```
this.messageForVM2 = ko.observable();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign your first viewmodel's Observable to your second viewmodel's `message` variable. Otherwise it will only be set the first time it loads.

Change:

```
this.message = ko.observable(vm1.messageForVM2());
```

To:

```
this.message = vm1.messageForVM2;
```

This way, `this.message` is a reference to `vm1.messageForVM2`, meaning both variables now share the same value.

---

```js
var viewModel1 = function(){
    this.messageForVM2 = ko.observable("");
    this.message = ko.observable("Hello this is vm1")
};

var viewModel2 = function(vm1){
    this.message = vm1.messageForVM2;
};


var masterVM = (function(){
    this.viewModel1 =  new viewModel1(),
    this.viewModel2 = new viewModel2(this.viewModel1);
})();

ko.applyBindings(masterVM)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h4>View Model 1</h4>
<div data-bind="with: viewModel1">
    <p data-bind="text: messageForVM2"></p>
    <input data-bind="value: messageForVM2, valueUpdate: 'input'" placeholder="Enter 'hello' here" />
</div>

<h4>View Model 2</h4>
<div data-bind="with: viewModel2">
    <!-- ko if: message() === "hello" -->
    <p data-bind="text:message"></p>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```